Find the word pairs


GCHQ: (3) ENIGMA ROTOR SCALE
The following list consists of pairs of words which are in some sense 'opposites' - and an odd word out. What are the pairs and which is the odd word out?











BOXING
DOWN
ERGO
GROG


HISS
HOME
MAIL
OGRE


OPPO
RATTLE
REFORM
SILENT


SITES
TILT
TOMTOM
WASH


UP







This is a puzzle originally set by GCHQ.

I think the odd one out is:

 HOME

With opposite pairs as follows...

 OPPO & SITES - the two opposite ends of the word 'opposites'.

 DOWN & UP - opposites in meaning.

 ERGO & OGRE - spell each other in reverse.

 BOXING & SILENT - can precede the opposites 'day' and 'night', respectively (Boxing Day, Silent Night).

 MAIL & WASH - can follow the opposites 'black' and 'white', respectively (Blackmail, Whitewash).

 GROG & TILT - encode each other in the 'atbash' cipher, where A=Z, B=Y, C=X etc. (i.e. G is 7 letters from the start of the alphabet, while T is 7 letters from the end; R and I are both 9 letters in from the ends; and O and L are both 12 letters in...)

 RATTLE & REFORM - anagrams of opposites: LATTER & FORMER.

 HISS & TOMTOM - encoded entirely by dots (HISS = .... .. ... ...) and dashes (TOMTOM = - --- -- - --- --) in Morse code.

